# QSQLITE with QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt-creator

Using `Qt 4.6.2` and `qtcreator`, I am working with a `cmake`/`ninja` managed project that makes use of the `QSQLITE` database driver from the Qt Framework. The environment makes use of the msvc compiler.

Strange thing happening is that I can't run the project in debug configuration (cmake ran with build option set to Debug) since :

```
QSqlDatabase::isDriverAvailable("QSQLITE")
```

always returns false and fails a `Q_ASSERT_X`. However, running the application from the command line then attaching the debugger is working (but really impractical).

The `dll` (debug and release) can be found in the `bin\sqldrivers` folders for the application, so they do exist.

Any clue on why does this behaviour occur?

Additional information:

- tested on qtcreator 3.1.1 and 3.3.0
- it is possible to bypass the debugger break by unchecking "Stop when qFatal() is called" in the QtCreator options (but I guess this will impair other errors as well)

Comment: What is the failing assertion? Could it simply be a working directory problem, where the DLL isn't found when your program is started by the debugger in a different directory?

Comment: I'm off work for today, but I'll check that in the morning.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not the case. Changing the working directory within the project tab of QT-Creator does not change the problem.